# on Login button click, i want to reset the password from "0000" to current dateformat, even after restart of application pswd should be dateformat

Tags: java, android, android-studio

what I mean is, i want to give the application to a user with password as "0000", after it's first use the password need to reset automatically to date format. so that the user cannot enter to the application with password "0000". Is there any way to code like this?

after login, the default password need to change to some other password (preferably date format)

I am hereby attaching the current status - java class code,  pls help

```
private EditText Name;
private EditText Password;
private Button Login;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    PermissionTest();
    LoginButton();
}
public void PermissionTest() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ;
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 10);

}

public void LoginButton() {
    Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    Login.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(Name.getText().toString().equals("admin") && Password.getText().toString().equals("0000")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PageActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "USER NAME AND PASSWORD INCORRECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
    );

}
```

Comment: Did you mean to tag JavaScript? Not Java?

Comment: initially password variable should be  = "0000"; after clicking Login button, value of password variable should be dateformat to string. and the dateformat should keep in sharedpreferance as password veriable. How to do this ??

Comment: I've changed the tag javascript to java.

Comment: i tried, but after restarting the app, we can login by entering "0000", that should not work.

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry, I un tagged JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

First time your app runs, put 0000 in sharepreference. After successful login delete it from sharepreference and substitute new password in it.

Comment: See here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm